# google QPX on Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-qpx-express-api

I am using QP Express api to gather data on flights from one place to the other in Android. When I run the app, the request is not sent to Google. What could I be missing? I have the client authorization in the manifest as shown below. What am I not doing right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.steve.myflights" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID"                      />/clients key
                android:value="*****(my client api key)**" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below is the MainActivity.java just in case it might be helpful

```
package com.example.steve.myflights;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.widget.EditText;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.*;

        import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
        import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
        import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
        import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.QPXExpressRequestInitializer;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.QPXExpress;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.model.FlightInfo;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.model.LegInfo;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.model.PassengerCounts;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.model.PricingInfo;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.model.SegmentInfo;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.model.SliceInfo;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.model.TripOption;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.model.TripOptionsRequest;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.model.TripsSearchRequest;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.model.SliceInput;
        import com.google.api.services.qpxExpress.model.TripsSearchResponse;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextOrigin;
    private EditText editTextArrival;
    private EditText editTextDestination;
    private EditText editTextFlightNum;
    private EditText editTextPrice;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String APPLICATION_NAME = "com.example.MyFlightsApp";

        final String API_KEY = "***APIKEY****";
        /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */

        HttpTransport httpTransport;
        /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
        final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        try {
            httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            PassengerCounts passengers= new PassengerCounts();
            passengers.setAdultCount(1);
            List<SliceInput> slices = new ArrayList<SliceInput>();
            SliceInput slice = new SliceInput();
            slice.setOrigin("NYC");
            slice.setDestination("JFK");
            slice.setDate("2015-11-11");
            slices.add(slice);
            TripOptionsRequest request= new TripOptionsRequest();
            request.setSolutions(1);
            request.setPassengers(passengers);
            request.setSlice(slices);
            TripsSearchRequest parameters = new TripsSearchRequest();
            parameters.setRequest(request);
            QPXExpress qpXExpress= new QPXExpress.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, null).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new QPXExpressRequestInitializer(API_KEY)).build();
            TripsSearchResponse list= qpXExpress.trips().search(parameters).execute();
            List<TripOption> tripResults=list.getTrips().getTripOption();
            String id;

            editTextArrival = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ediTextArrival);
            editTextOrigin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ediTextOrigin);
            editTextDestination = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ediTextDestination);
            editTextFlightNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ediTextFlightNum);
            editTextPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ediTextPrice);

            for(int i=0; i<tripResults.size(); i++) {
                //Trip Option ID
                id= tripResults.get(i).getId();
                //Slice
                List<SliceInfo> sliceInfo= tripResults.get(i).getSlice();
                for(int j=0; j<sliceInfo.size(); j++) {
                    int duration= sliceInfo.get(j).getDuration();
                    List<SegmentInfo> segInfo= sliceInfo.get(j).getSegment();
                    for(int k=0; k<segInfo.size(); k++) {
                        FlightInfo flightInfo=segInfo.get(k).getFlight();
                        editTextFlightNum.setText(flightInfo.getNumber());
                        List<LegInfo> leg=segInfo.get(k).getLeg();
                        for(int l=0; l<leg.size(); l++) {
                            editTextArrival.setText(leg.get(1).getAircraft());
                            editTextDestination.setText(leg.get(1).getDestination());
                            editTextOrigin.setText(leg.get(1).getOrigin());

                        }
                    }
                }

                //Pricing
                List<PricingInfo> priceInfo= tripResults.get(i).getPricing();
                for(int p=0; p<priceInfo.size(); p++) {

                    editTextPrice.setText(priceInfo.get(p).getSaleTotal());
                }
            }
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
       // System.exit(1);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add permission to access network and know the network in your manifest file.